# How to disable the grey mask when tap on a <a> element?

Tags: html, css, progressive-web-apps, hybrid

I'm trying to make a Hybrid app. In a webpage, there are many buttons written like

```
<a href="#">
    <div style = "height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: #00ff00; margin: 32px"></div>
</a>
```

When I tap these buttons and hold my thumb, there will be a grey mask on top of the buttons. How can I disable this.

Test Device: iPhone X, both real machine and simulator

[image: Example]

Comment: pls share correct example

Comment: What device are you testing this with?

Answer (score -1):

Seems it's to do with `<a href="#">`. Removing href solves the problem. I just need to find a way to `preventDefault`.

Comment: This should have been an edit to your original post, as you say it doesn't solve the problem.